# How to Trigger Validate Function on ngOnChanges in validation directive in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-validation, angular-validator

***How to Trigger Validate Function on ngOnChanges in validation directive in Angular?***

I detected ngOnChanges, but its not working to trigger validate function

```js
@Directive({
        selector: '[uppercase]',
        providers: [{
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: RdUppercaseDirective,
            multi: true
        }]
    })
    export class RdUppercaseDirective implements Validator, OnChanges  {
        @Input('uppercase') uppercase: any;

        r = new rdValidators;

        validate(control: AbstractControl): {
            [key: string]: any
        } | null {
            let u = this.uppercase === 'false' || this.uppercase === false ? false : true;
            if(!control.value)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if(u === false)
            {
                return null;
            }            
            var result = (/[a-z]/.test(control.value));
            return control.dirty  && control.value ? result ? { 'uppercase' : true } : null : null;
        }

        ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
            if(changes.uppercase){
                  //**How to Trigger Validate Function Here!**
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would have to have controll reference to do that.

Comment: How to working with control reference

Comment: You must provide it somehow. How would I know that? I don't even know the context of that directive. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score -1):

Whenever validate function is been called, we will be having the control. This control will be passed by default when the Angular validates the form(default behavior). But, when we call the validate function in ngOnChanges, we need to have the control(AbstractControl) instance, for that we can store the parameter abstract control in a private property and we can use it when we call manually.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[uppercase]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: RdUppercaseDirective,
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class RdUppercaseDirective implements Validator, OnChanges  {
    @Input('uppercase') uppercase: any;
    private _control: AbstractControl;

    r = new rdValidators;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): {
        [key: string]: any
    } | null {
        this._control = control
        let u = this.uppercase === 'false' || this.uppercase === false ? false : true;
        if(!control.value)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if(u === false)
        {
            return null;
        }            
        var result = (/[a-z]/.test(control.value));
        return control.dirty  && control.value ? result ? { 'uppercase' : true } : null : null;
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
        if(changes.uppercase){
              //** you can access _control object here to call your validation function 

              this._control.updateValueAndValidity(); 
              //** this will update value and call validation function. 
        }
```